# QRcode generated not storing in the path given

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code

Using [SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-qrcode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/simple-qrcode/), I am trying to generate QRCode and store it.

```
\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, '/assets/uploads/'.$reservation_id.'.svg');
```

Which returns following error,

```
"file_put_contents(/assets/uploads/15525609678807.svg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "/..../vendor/simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode/src/SimpleSoftwareIO/QrCode/BaconQrCodeGenerator.php",
"line": 85,
```

Comment: Could it be that the path in which you are trying to store the QR code is not existing? Would explain the error message. It could also be, that your path is just wrong.

Comment: the path exists but the file not, as their docs, the second param for the file in which the code to be stored. Thanks @Tim

Comment: Where is your assets folder? Does it in public folder or in direct root.

Comment: @MayankDudakiya It's in root.

Comment: Try to add ../assets like `\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, '../assets/uploads/'.$reservation_id.'.svg');` and check image generated into the particular folder or not.
Assets never be in root folder. If I am not wrong then you've moved assets folder in root to remove public.

Comment: Try this `\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, '../assets/uploads/'.$reservation_id.'.svg');`

Comment: Yes, I have moved all the files and folders from public to root. And so ./assets in root. @MayankDudakiya

Comment: even I tried with ```\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, $reservation_id.'.svg');```, returns same error.@MayankDudakiya

Comment: You should never change the flow of Laravel. This is not proper way to remove public from laravel. All the assets should be in public folder.

Comment: ok, I did revert the changes now but still facing same. Can you please explain how the issue can be solved. @MayankDudakiya

Comment: Now please try with  `$public_path = public_path('assets/upload');` this will give you public path then add rest of the thing like $qr_path = $public_path.'/'.$reservation_id.'.svg';   \QrCode::generate($qr_path);
Also please veryfiy that public path should come proper.

Comment: Added base path which works fine, Thanks @MayankDudakiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works,

`\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, base_path().$reservation_id.'.svg');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = '/assets/uploads/';
if(!\File::exists(public_path($path))) {
    \File::makeDirectory(public_path($path));
}
$file_path = $path . $reservation_id . '.svg';

\QrCode::generate($reservation_id, $file_path);
```

I hope it will help you, this is work fine for me.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answer given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.